# What's the difference between queryAll and querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, dom, selectors-api

The [definitions from the DOM Standard](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parentnode-query) seems almost exactly the same, and I don't understand the difference.

What is the difference between `queryAll` and `querySelectorAll`.

The evaluation logic from DOM standard is below, but I am not smart enough to understand it.

**`query` & `queryAll`**

> To match a relative selectors string relativeSelectors against a set, run these steps:
>
> Let s be the result of parse a relative selector from relativeSelectors against set. [SELECTORS]
>
> If s is failure, throw a JavaScript TypeError.
>
> Return the result of evaluate a selector s using :scope elements set. [SELECTORS]
>
> The query(relativeSelectors) method must return the first result of running match a relative selectors string relativeSelectors against a set consisting of context object, and null if the result is an empty list.
>
> The queryAll(relativeSelectors) method must return an Elements array initialized with the result of running match a relative selectors string relativeSelectors against a set consisting of context object.

**`querySelector` & `querySelectorAll`**

> To scope-match a selectors string selectors against a node, run these steps:
>
> Let s be the result of parse a selector selectors. [SELECTORS]
>
> If s is failure, throw a JavaScript TypeError.
>
> Return the result of evaluate a selector s against node's root using scoping root node and scoping method scope-filtered. [SELECTORS].
>
> The querySelector(selectors) method must return the first result of running scope-match a selectors string selectors against the context object, and null if the result is an empty list otherwise.
>
> The querySelectorAll(selectors) method must return the static result of running scope-match a selectors string selectors against the context object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`query()` and `queryAll()` accept a relative selector string, whereas `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` do not. A relative selector is basically a selector which may be partial and start with a combinator:

```
var parentNode = document.getElementById('parentNode'); // document.querySelector('#parentNode');

// Find .childNode elements that are direct descendants (children) of parentNode
// This cannot be done with querySelectorAll() using the existing reference to parentNode
parentNode.queryAll('> .childNode');
// querySelectorAll does allow getting all descendants of parentNode though
parentNode.querySelectorAll('.childNode');
```

But more importantly, `queryAll()` returns a *live* `Elements[]` array whereas the `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll()` is static, which means the nodes in that list are not updated when changes are made to their respective DOM elements.

In terms of their functionality, `query()` and `queryAll()` may be more analogous to `find()` and `findAll()`, defined in [Selectors API level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api2) — where you'll also find the definition of a relative selector — as both method groups accept and work with relative selectors. Note that `findAll()` also returns a static `NodeList`, so they are still not completely identical.

Comment: It's also important to add what each function returns. One returns an `Elements` array, which contains live nodes and the other returns a static `NodeList`.

Comment: @OozeMeister: Good point. That's also what makes `queryAll()` different from `findAll()`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Note that the current polyfill [barberboy/dom-elements](https://github.com/barberboy/dom-elements) for `query()` & `queryAll()` does not support relative selectors. [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kabirile/1/edit?html,js,console,output) & [github issue](https://github.com/barberboy/dom-elements/issues/2)

Comment: Update: [barderboy/dom-elements](https://github.com/barberboy/dom-elements/issues/2) now supports relative selectors! [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kabirile/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: This should probably be a separate question entirely, but why are there specs for both query[All] and find[All] if they are so close? Are they competing specs or are both likely to be implemented?

Comment: @Nathan Bubna: Good question. Actually, it was decided some time prior to my answer that Selectors API would be merged into DOM4; I did not notice this note in the Selectors API 2 spec until recently. I am not sure of the current fate of find[All].

Comment: Actually `parentNode.querySelectorAll(parentNode.nodeName + ' > .childNode');` is equivalent to `parentNode.queryAll('> .childNode');` (except for the static/dynamic part).

Comment: @Nux: No, it's not. What that does is match .childNode elements with a parent that happens to have the same tag name as the parentNode reference, which doesn't at all imply that they're children *of parentNode*. For example, if parentNode is a div and its .childNode descendant is a child of another div that's nested inside it, such that the entire structure can be represented by the selector `div#parentNode > div > .childNode`, that statement would match that .childNode even though it is not a child of parentNode. The qSA equivalent is `parentNode.querySelectorAll(':scope > .childNode');`.

Comment: @Nux: In any case, queryAll is gone now and I have no idea what to do with my answer. But thanks for the edit anyway.

Answer (score 19):

## 2016 Update

### `queryAll` was removed from the DOM spec

Currently the most important difference between `queryAll` and `querySelectorAll` is that `queryAll` (as well as `query`) was **removed from the DOM specification**.

The current version of the DOM specification is available at:

- http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/

Note: https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/ is an outdated fork of the DOM Standard
(see [Fork tracking](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Fork_tracking) on the [WHATWG Wiki](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Main_Page) and [the comment by Domenic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23269785/whats-the-difference-between-queryall-and-queryselectorall/38245620?noredirect=1#comment63923286_38245620) for more info).

### Last mention

The last version that included `query` and `queryAll` was published on 15 March 2016:

- http://web.archive.org/web/20160315085447/https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/

  - See sections
    [4.2.3. Interface ParentNode](http://web.archive.org/web/20160315085447/https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-parentnode) and
    [4.2.6. Collections: Elements](http://web.archive.org/web/20160315085447/https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#element-collections)

### Removal

The next version doesn't mention `query` or `queryAll` anywhere:

- http://web.archive.org/web/20160329233515/https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/

  - See section
    [4.2.6. Mixin ParentNode](http://web.archive.org/web/20160329233515/https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-parentnode)

### Current specification

All occurances of `query` or `queryAll` 
in the DOM standard [were commented out](https://github.com/whatwg/dom/commit/10b6cf1ba02806220d5461a3bdb7939728b73635) by Anne van Kesteren on March 29, 2016.

The current DOM specification (as of July 2016) doesn't mention `query` or `queryAll` at all:

- http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/

`querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` are in section
[4.2.6 Mixin ParentNode](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-parentnode).

It seems that currently the only reliable API is `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`
(see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572735/javascript-getelement-by-href/37820644#37820644) for more details) and according to [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/whatwg/dom/issues/39#issuecomment-231056316) `query` and `queryAll` will not be available until the JavaScript subclassing of built-ins is implemented in the browsers and even then it will be unlikely to return a live Elements[] array as described in [the answer by BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23269785/whats-the-difference-between-queryall-and-queryselectorall/23270016#23270016).

### Browser support

As of June 2016 there is no mention of `query` and `queryAll` on MDN:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=queryall

On the other hand `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` are well documented and widely supported:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Browser support of `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` according to [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/queryselector) as of June 2016:

[image: caniuse.com/queryselector]
(See: http://caniuse.com/queryselector for up to date info)

There is no info available on the support of `query` and `queryAll`.

### More info

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572735/javascript-getelement-by-href/37820644#37820644) for more info on the usage and browser support of `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Your links are all to an outdated fork of the up-to-date DOM Standard at http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/. For more information see https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Fork_tracking. (We have repeatedly asked the W3C to stop copying and rebranding our specifications, but they have not.)

Comment: @Domenic Thanks for the info. I updated the answer so that all links now point to dom.spec.whatwg.org and I added a note on the outdated fork on w3c.org. I didn't know that the w3c fork is outdated. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Domenic: I noticed the spec doesn't mention relative selectors at all. Are there any plans to allow querySelector and querySelectorAll to accept relative selectors? I'm glad the confusing new names have been removed entirely but I'm not a fan of having to prepend my drill-down selectors with :scope every time.

Comment: @Domenic: Never mind - I figured out that making qSA accept relative selectors would break the current behavior (see `element.querySelectorAll('E F')` vs `element.querySelectorAll(':scope E F')`). I see now why the new methods were added in the first place...

Comment: @BoltClock do I understand it correctly that `qSA` with a `:scope` placed at the beginning of the selector "fixes" the behavior, i.e. it behaves as one would expect (only selects descendants of `element`)?

Comment: @BoltClock you just made my day :)