# getElementById from url hashtag

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a mega menu with the code below.

This is the link from the menu to show the mega menu

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="mmBtn"></li>
```

And this is the javascript

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('mmCat');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("mmBtn");

// Closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// Open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// Close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// Close it from outside
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use a link like this instead to get the ID and not reload the page and not showing the hashtag in addressbar?

```
<a href="test.com/products#mmBtn">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript getElement by href?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572735/javascript-getelement-by-href)

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Here are the steps: **1.** Bind click event on all the anchors having hash in it `a[href*="#"]`. **2.** In handler, extract the hash of the clicked link **3.** Scroll to that element **4.** Prevent redirect.

Comment: Oh, that's over my head. But I will give it a try and Google for solutions for all 4 steps.